# SSL Error while trying to access JIRA using Python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am getting SSL Error while trying to access JIRA API from python application.

The error message reads -

**requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.companyurl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))**

```
def oauth():
    key_cert_data = None
    with open('/scripts/jira_privatekey.pem', 'r') as key_cert_file:
        key_cert_data = key_cert_file.read()
    oauth_dict = {
                'access_token': 'XXXXXX',
                'access_token_secret': 'YYYYYY',
                'consumer_key': 'OauthKey',
                'key_cert': key_cert_data
            }
    return oauth_dict
url = 'https://jira.companyurl.com'



jira = JIRA(url, oauth=oauth())
```

could you please advise how to overcome this SSL error?

Comment: Seems like your company’s JIRA’s SSL certificate is invalid. You can override it locally by passing options duct to the JIRA builder with verify=False

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can i pass verify=False?

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this by passing `verify=False`:

```py
def oauth():
    key_cert_data = None
    with open('/scripts/jira_privatekey.pem', 'r') as key_cert_file:
        key_cert_data = key_cert_file.read()
    oauth_dict = {
                'access_token': 'XXXXXX',
                'access_token_secret': 'YYYYYY',
                'consumer_key': 'OauthKey',
                'key_cert': key_cert_data
            }
    return oauth_dict
url = 'https://jira.companyurl.com'



jira = JIRA(url, oauth=oauth(), options={"verify": False})
```

As always in this case, please use this as a temporary override and not as in production since it can introduce security issues.